# Windows 7 program installs on windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, installation

Simple question, I've recently bought a new laptop with Windows 8.1 while previously I've had Windows 7. I've noticed a lot of programs don't have an install option for Windows 8, do installers for Windows 7 also have the ablility install programs on Windows 8?

Comment: If it installed on Windows 7 there is no reason it wouldn't work on Windows 8.  What error do you get exactly?

Comment: I haven't tried to do it yet, I was anticipating and I couldn't find any web results on this so I thought it would be good to ask. If It was found you couldn't install windows 7 programs I would probably downgrade the OS

Comment: Some things may not work, but expect most programs to work.

Comment: @Shardj - I have not found a single Windows 7 program that was unable to be installed **UNLESS** the installer itself was to blame.  At the very least you should have **tried** before you asked this question.

Comment: If you have any problem try using the Compatibility mode by doing `Right click` to the executable > `Properties` > `Compatibility` Tab.

Answer (score 2):

As with the transition from DOS to Windows, Windows to Windows NT, NT to 2000, XP to Vista, and Vista to Seven, there is backwards compatibility.